# Block WCF message logging in client application at run time

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have seen plenty of ways to turn on WCF message logging, but what I want to prevent WCF message logging in a client desktop application (WPF or WinForms)? I am worried that some power user will figure out how to turn on logging by editing the config file and have a way to store the sensitive information that my application is sending to the remote services. It seems that the user has an incredible amount of control over message logging if they know what they are doing. I have searched all over SO and MSDN looking for a way to secure this setting and haven't been able to find anything that can't be overridden by just editing the config file.

Comment: Is this the right way of looking at the problem? What if the user routed all the service calls through a proxy and logged the messages that way?

Comment: Could that be done if the service is using SSL?

Regardless, I would still like to know the answer to my original question.

Comment: @Geo242, most definitely.  My favorite tool for WCF message debugging is Fiddler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything the computer can do, the user can do.  This is an immutable law which can not be escaped.  It is why there are Keygens, it is why there is software cracking, and it is why it is not possible for your program to generate a message, but not allow the user to see it.

You can make it harder for them by having a watchdog which checks if logging is enabled, and throwing an error, but the below is just a short list of what they can do to usurp such superficial attempts to evade the user's access to the messaging:

- [Fiddler / Proxy Server](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
- [MITM with self-signed certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8145/does-https-prevent-man-in-the-middle-attacks-by-proxy-server)
- [Hook on SChannel functions exported from secur32.dll](http://blog.elevenpaths.com/2013/11/hookme-tool-for-intercepting.html)
- Decompiling the application running on their computer, possibly modifying it to remove any obstructions you include
  This sounds hard, but is far easier than you would imagine.  A couple of `nop`s and all of that clever code you used to detect the user from logging messages is gone.
- Take a memory dump around the time that a message is being constructed.  The text of the message will sit in memory, waiting to be reused, long (>200ms) after it has been sent.
- Run with a debugger and put a breakpoint on some WCF function
- etc...

### Ignoring the limitations

In terms of checking whether tracing is enabled, you can use a construct like the following:

```
private static bool IsWcfTracingEnabled()
{
    TraceSource ts = new TraceSource("System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging");
    return ts.Listeners.Count > 0;
}
```

Which will return `false` for:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
      <listeners>
        <clear />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

And `true` for:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
      <listeners>
        <clear />
        <add name="messages"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="c:\logs\messages.svclog" />
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Or:

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" />
  </sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem I am really trying to prevent is the storage of the logging information. If the current user has access to see the messages sent during their session, that's not that big of a deal. The user machines are shared though, and I don't want the information stored so one user can read the logs of another. I am looking into filtering specific data in the message logs, but that seems to be easy to get around too.